# Linking MVC terms, front-end, back-end and data processing

Tags: django, model-view-controller, architecture

I am a little confused while linking these terms together. First, let me explain my understanding of these terms, followed by my query:

- **Front End**: What user sees (HTML, css, javascript etc). Can also be called `Presentation` Layer (corresponds to templates, css files etc.)
- **Back End**: The rest of your codebase.

So, as per my understanding, the whole `MVC` (Model-View-Controller) architecture will fall under `Back End` with:

- **Model** acting as the `Data Access` layer
- **View** acting as the `Application` and `logic` layer
- **Controller**  -- not sure what this corresponds to (I know this refers to url mapping in context of Django)

Queries:

1. Is my understanding correct, or am I trying to confuse the 3-tier architecture (data, application (logic), presentation) with MVC ?
2. For the Data Layer, I am populating my database through scripts external to the MVC Web architecture codebase. These scripts fetch and process data before loading into the database. What should I call these set of Data Fetch & Processing scripts (in terms of software-architectural terms) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take a lot of terminology from a long history of software development, and make a simple coherent unification...  Probably not going to work real well...

Front-End vs Back-End generally refers to the thing that the user interfaces with vs the "everything else" that back-end refers to.  But there are no hard lines here.  Some people would consider templates back-end, some people would only consider the database back-end...  This is just too squishy of a term to use for much value.

Your understanding of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is a little off...

Model is definitely where data access usually occurs, but it also usually had your application logic as well.  The idea here is that your application exists independently of the web application that surrounds it.

The View should just have the presentation and data-input.  It is not supposed to contain significant application or business logic.  You want to shift as much of that to the model as possible.  Some logic does inevitably bleed through, but it should be minimized.

The Controller is interface between the model and the view.  It is the glue that takes the input from the view, passes it to the model, where the business logic acts on it.  Based on the response from the model controller's responsibility is to provide data back to the view.

Finally, the scripts that load the database are orthogonal to your web application architecture.  They sound like [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) scripts, but I would have to know a lot more about them to place them in your architecture.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the answer. I have a few follow ups Based on how files are distributed in django: 1) models.py contains just the db structure and the data modification functions 2) views.py contains the main application & presentation logic -- maybe I can decouple this into two: logic.py (for logic) and views.py (for presentation).

Comment: I thought of ETL but I am not sure I would classify those scripts as ETL. Let me give you more information about those scripts: Let's say I am building a financial analytics website. These data scripts pulls data, runs several models on the data to assign different sort of probabilities / classification etc (basically more of data processing than transformation) and then loads this highly "enriched" data into the DB.

Comment: I'd still call it ETL.  "transform" is a broad category.